# multiple files renamed in directory, need htaccess rule to redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Is it possible in the .htaccess file to redirect multiple file names, for example I use to have files such as:

```
/publications/publications-1.php
/publications/publications-2.php
/publications/publications-3.php
```

I want to change them to their new file names:

```
/publications/1.php
/publications/2.php
/publications/3.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this in directory where you have your php files,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+).php$ publications-$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Never knew I could put a .htaccess file into a sub directory too! 

However I have an error: HTTP ERROR 500 'page is not working'

Comment: what is your original url? please provide full url you are putting in browser.

Comment: So the old url would have been: http://www.biometricsltd.com/publications/publications-data.php

And the new: http://www.biometricsltd.com/publications/data.php

Answer (score 1):

Add a htaccess file to your webroot directory and add a rule like this:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^publications/(.*)\.php$ /publications-$1.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
## Results
# publications/data.php => publications-data.php
```

It maps any request that matched the condition to the corresponding php file **under the hood**. If you need a redirect instead, append a `R` flag to the rule.

In case you need a more general rule to match anything in the first segment, try this instead:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.php$ /$1-$2.php [L,QSA]
## Results
# foo/bar.php => foo-bar.php
```

And one last thing to note; make sure apache's rewrite module is enabled and htaccess files are allowed (`AllowOverride All` in your httpd.conf):

```bsh
# If enabled, outputs something like this:
# rewrite_module (shared)
apachectl -M | grep rewrite # It's apache2ctl on some platforms

# If not enabled; you can enable it using this on most platforms: 
a2enmod rewrite
apachectl restart
```